# What would the advantage of a functional operation be in this situation?

Tags: java

I'm working my way through the MOOC.fi Java course and one of the methods I've written is

```
public void printMeals(){
    for (String meal: meals){
        System.out.println(meal);
    }
}
```

Netbeans is suggesting I use a functional operation, which converts the code to:

```
public void printMeals(){
    meals.forEach((meals) -> {
        System.out.println(meal);
    });
}
```

I have a passing familiarity with lambda functions (which a cursory Google search tells me this is), but I'm not sure what the advantage here is. Does the suggested form perform better? Is using a lambda function here considered best practice?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297162/why-should-i-use-functional-operations-instead-of-a-for-loop

Comment: A good reason to uninstall NetBeans.

Comment: @Martheen So basically "There isn't one here". Thank you for the link though. It's very informative.

Comment: The second example can be rewritten to `meals.forEach(System.out::println);` which might be easier to read in comparison to the traditional loop (especially when the code requires more logic like mapping). It's however harder to debug and as long as you don't use parallel streams (which requires expert knowledge in most cases!), that code will not be faster than the traditional or advanced for loop. I usually prefer normal loops as soon as one of the lambdas needs a `{`.